# Multiple ACF values in get_post_meta for Woocommerce Additional Information tab

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I'm adding extra information in the "Additional Information" tab in Woocommerce. One row needs to contain 3 different ACF fields:

- unpackaged_height
- unpackaged_length
- unpackaged_width

I can't seem to get this to work with multiple fields. I have tried the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 'custom_product_additional_information', 10, 2 );
function custom_product_additional_information( $product_attributes, $product ) {

$product_attributes[ 'attribute_' . 'custom-two' ] = array(
    'label' => __('Product Dimensions', 'text-domain'),
    'value' => get_post_meta($product->get_ID(), 'unpackaged_height', true),
    'value' => get_post_meta($product->get_ID(), 'unpackaged_length', true),
    'value' => get_post_meta($product->get_ID(), 'unpackaged_width', true),
);

return $product_attributes;
```

}

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide more informations about the output of your function ? What is wrong ? any error ? Also, why are you using `get_post_meta()` and not `get_field()` ?

Comment: I am only getting 1 output (unpackaged_width), not all 3. No error. I'm using get_post_meta as I'm calling the ACF field in a product page

Comment: Even on a product page you can use `get_field()`

Answer (score 0):

When you write :

```
    'value' => get_post_meta($product->get_ID(), 'unpackaged_height', true),
    'value' => get_post_meta($product->get_ID(), 'unpackaged_length', true),
    'value' => get_post_meta($product->get_ID(), 'unpackaged_width', true),
```

you are changing the value of `value` each time. So the last value is the only one you can see because each value of `value` is overwriting the previous one

You can try

```
'value' => array(
    get_post_meta($product->get_ID(), 'unpackaged_height', true),
    get_post_meta($product->get_ID(), 'unpackaged_length', true),
    get_post_meta($product->get_ID(), 'unpackaged_width', true),
)
```

or use different indexes for each post_met instead of just `value`